# What distribution do you suggest for daily use?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, osx

I use my computer everyday for various reasons:

1. programming in c++, android(java), java(in general)
2. listening to music(spotify), watching movies
3. browsing internet, watching youtube clips
4. writing various documents
5. studying in general (I am a student)
6. flashing custom roms to my android phone (now and then)

Currently I am using ubuntu 13.04, but it is not really well polished (I think...). I would like to ask for your tips and suggestions, what would fit my needs the most?

I really like global menu in ubuntu. To be honest, I really like the whole shell of macs osx. I would buy mac for sure, if I had money for it. For obvious reasons, I have to stick with searching for perfect linux distro which has features similar to osx :)

So, your tips and suggestions are more then welcome. Thank you!

Comment: I'd say Ubuntu is good enough for these activities. I have experience with Ubuntu, Fedora and CentOS. Other than Android programming, I did everything you mention in the list.

Comment: You can do your jobs in every linux distro... but you have to customize them for your purpose...

Comment: Read this [blog](http://www.dedoimedo.com/) from time to time. The author has lots of Linux distribution reviews.

Answer (score 2):

I'd get `Linux Mint (16)`. Simple, elegant, and ported from Ubuntu (which means you can do almost anything with it).